# count until a character is found then set counter to zero after appending it to an array

Tags: c++

so I have a file that's structured like this

```
01
,
10
11
00
,
00
;
```

each line can only hold 2 0s or 1s, and there can be any amount of lines over 0 in between the commas and I need to count every line until there's a comma and append that value to an array then set the counter to 0. if the function finds a ; it saves that value then breaks the loop

currently I'm stuck on getting it to count up correctly, maybe I'm just not understanding how getline works

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>



int main()
{
  std::string line[4];
  std::ifstream infile("in.txt");
  std::ofstream outfile("inData.txt");


  int x;
  while(!infile.eof())
  {
    getline(infile,line[0],'\n'); // tried with a , for \n and that correctly increases x for every comma
    ++x;
    std::cout << "x: " << x << "\n"; 


    // if(getline(infile, line[0],';')) {break;}
    // need to break if ; is found but from what I've seen it just makes it iterate once then break when I was using a , in the first getline
  }
  std::cin.get();
}
```

Comment: `int x;` is not initialized, so `++x;` invokes *undefined behavior*

Comment: Did you try stepping through the code with a debugger to see what exactly happens during reading the input? Unrelated to this error but relevant: [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/7691729)

Comment: Why is `line` an array? For detecting `,` and `;` can't you just use `line[0] == ","` and `line[0] == ";"`?

Answer (score 1):

To explain you simply how the `getfile` function works :

- It takes as first parameter the file (or more generally any object of type input stream) to be processed, as second parameter the object where the result will be obtained (here a string). The third parameter allows to define the end-of-line delimiter, which is by default the `\n` character.
- Then, this function will "read" the first line of your file, up to the delimiter, then copy the result in the string.
- Each time you call this function again, it will "read" the next line, until the end of the file.
- When you reach the end of the file, the `eof()` function will return `true`, which will stop your while loop.

This is how the file reading works.

Now to the problems with your program:

- First, why is `line` an array? Actually, you only use the first value of this array.
- Secondly, you are using the `++x` statement. This statement allows you to increment (add 1) the value of x. Now, at the beginning, x has no value. So, how do you want to increment it if it has no value. You have to put a value to it.
- Then you need to know if you encounter any special characters, which are `,` and `;`. You can simply check the value of the line (which is in the `line` variable), to see if it matches any of these values.

I'll leave you a working draft of the code, don't hesitate if you have other questions!

```cpp
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>
    
    
    
    int main()
    {
        std::string line;
        std::ifstream infile("in.txt");
        std::ofstream outfile("inData.txt");
    
        int x = 0; //You need to set a default value because when you do ++x, you increment the 
        //value of x, but if x has no value, you can't increment it
    
        while (!infile.eof())
        {
            getline(infile, line); // It retrieves the next line of the file
    
            //Here you can make different tests for the particular values you are looking for
            if (line == ";")
                break;
            if (line == ",")
            {
                //do what you need when you find a comma
                ;
            }
            ++x;
            std::cout << "x: " << x << "\n";
        }
        std::cin.get();
    }
```

Comment: `When you reach the end of the file, the eof() function will return false,` I hope you meant that it will return `true`

Comment: Small mistake from me, thank you!

Comment: I think when I was trying to initialize line it didn't work because of some other weird code I had and making it an array fixed it, I guess I just didn't change it when I removed that

Comment: ok so I tried this code and it incrementing for each line worked, but it doesn't do anything when there's a comma. maybe there's some issue with the file but I couldn't find anything, do you know if its an issue with the code or the file and what should I do to set x to 0 then just print something to see if its working for now

Comment: It is normal that nothing happens when there is a comma. 
Try to understand the code. 
Look at the comments to help you.